# Is there any reason why thisptr is offset by 1 byte?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wish I could make a minimal example that had the same issue but I couldn't replicate it. Here's an abstract of what my code does:

```
unsigned long long pbase = 0,
                   pchild = 0;

class base
{
public:
    static unsigned long long offset( )
    {
        return sizeof( int ) * 0;
    }

    unsigned & get( )
    {
        pbase = ( unsigned long long )this;
        return *( unsigned * )( pbase + offset( ) );
    }
};

class child: public base
{
public:
    static unsigned long long offset( )
    {
        return sizeof( int ) * 1;
    }

    unsigned & childget( )
    {
        pchild = ( unsigned long long )this;
        return *( unsigned * )( pchild + offset( ) );
    }
};

unsigned mem[ 2 ] { 0xFF0000FF, 0xAA0000AA };

child & c = reinterpret_cast< child & >( mem[ 0 ] );

#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    using std::endl;

    auto a = c.get( );
    auto b = c.childget( );

    std::cout << std::hex << &c << endl
        << &mem[ 0 ] << endl << endl
        << pbase << endl
        << a << endl << endl
        << pchild << endl
        << b;
}
```

When entering the `childget` function, the thisptr is fine. When entering the base `get` function, the thisptr is 1 byte off. I figured that this might be because, since the child class is empty and inheriting the base class, the base class starts 1 byte off because all classes must be at least 1 in size. What could possibly cause this behavior and how do I fix it?

Comment: Posting code that does *not* exhibit the problem doesn't help a lot. Failure to duplicate it in a minimal example only adds to the suspicion of undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: The use of `reinterpret_cast` and c-style casting to/from pointers, with pointer-arithmetic involved, makes me suspect that you are invoking undefined behavior (and that the undefined behavior is leading to your compiler and/or optimizer outputting code containing a misaligned pointer)

Comment: Invoking undefined behavior could cause it (remember undefined behavior can cause literally *anything*, by definition)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The pointer is obtained successfully. Somewhere between `p->` and the function call is causing the pointer to be incremented by 1. The thing is, p does not change. I have no idea why the thisptr is incremented except for possibly a class structuring issu